# How to deal with unresolved related model during test migrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have an app in production that is very okay. I am currently adding unit tests but so far the tests are failing because of a migration-related error during the creation of the test database.

```
ValueError: Related model 'my_app.my_model' cannot be resolved
```

Here is the full [Stack Trace](https://pastebin.com/mr1KgkDi)

Some background info: I had a model `MyModel` that was a ForeignKey on other models in different apps. I renamed the model to `NewModel`. I also renamed all the ForeignKeys from `my_model` to `new_model`. Django migrations asked whether I renamed the model, I accepted, and I have verified the renaming was done correctly in the migration files.

My test case is something like this:

```
class DoerTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        A.objects.create(title='Test A')
        NewModel.objects.create(title='Test New Model')

    def setUp(self):
        a = A.objects.first()
        new_model = NewModel.objects.first()
        B.objects.create(a=a, new_model=new_model)

    def test_doer(self):
        b = B.objects.first()
        ...
```

How can I resolve this without possibly interfering with the existing migrations?